# integral of $f^p$ on a $\sigma$-finite measure

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I have a σ-finite measure  on $(X,\mathbb{F},\mu)$ and a non negative function $f$ that is measurable on X. Further there exists a $p>0$ such that 
$$
\int_X f^p d\mu\:\text{ exists.}
$$

It is required to show that 
$$
\int_X f^p d\mu=p\int_{[0,\infty]}t^{p-1}\mu\big(\{x\in X: f(x)\geq t\}\big)dt
$$

I would be grateful for some hints, because I am not really coming a step forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\mu\{x\mid f(x)>t\}=\int_X\boldsymbol 1_{\{x\mid f(x)>t\}}\mathrm d\mu(x),$$
and use Fubini.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit?